# director error in corona

Tags: coronasdk

settings.lua

```
 local lang_table = {
    {image = display.newImage("en.png"), x = 600, y = 400, lang = "1033", i = 1},
    {image = display.newImage("fr.png"), x = 600, y = 400, lang = "fr", i = 2},
    {image = display.newImage("dk.png"), x = 600, y = 400, lang = "dk", i = 3},
    {image = display.newImage("ge.png"), x = 600, y = 400, lang = "ge", i = 4}                                      }

local function changelanguage (event)
  if event.phase == "ended" then
    lang_table[event.target.i].image.isVisible = false
    if event.target.i == 4 then
      lang_table[1].image.isVisible = true
      _G.value = event.target.lang
      director:changeScene("settings")
    else
      lang_table[event.target.i+1].image.isVisible = true
      _G.value = lang_table[event.target.i+1].lang
      director:changeScene("settings")
   end
  end
  return true
end

for i = 1,#lang_table do 
    local img_display = lang_table[i].image
    img_display.x = lang_table[i].x
    img_display.y = lang_table[i].y
    img_display.i = lang_table[i].i
    img_display.lang = lang_table[i].lang

    if _G.value ~= lang_table[i].lang then
        img_display.isVisible = false
    end

    img_display:addEventListener("touch", changelanguage)
    langGroup:insert(img_display)
end
```

When I touch the image,changelanguage function is being invoked.In that function there is

```
director:changeScene
```

but this is not working.Basically,what I want is that whenever there is touch event to the image I want the same lua file to be called.But this is not happening.Then What I did was changed the function "changelanguage" to

```
_G.t =1
local function changelanguage (event)
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        lang_table[event.target.i].image.isVisible = false
        if event.target.i == 7 then
            lang_table[1].image.isVisible = true
            _G.value = event.target.lang
            director:changeScene("settings")
        else
            lang_table[event.target.i+1].image.isVisible = true
            _G.value = lang_table[event.target.i+1].lang
            if _G.t ==1 then
                director:changeScene("..\settings")
                _G.t = _G.t+1
            elseif _G.t ==2 then
                director:changeScene("..\..\settings")
            end
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

Now, it is working.But I dont know why is this happening.Can anyone suggest me why is this happening.Cant I use the same `director:changeScene("settings")` to change the scene again and again on touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Director to change to a scene you are already in, eg, calling director:changeScene("settings") from within settings.lua, no.

You can do this in Storyboard, however. (It may be worth considering a switch if this is something you will be doing a lot of, alternatively you could make a file such as reset.lua and write functions within there to effectively reload any scene you liked simply by changing to reset and back to the previous scene again.)

Comment: Would it be worth creating an empty scene to switch to, which switches right back to the current scene?

Comment: Personal opinion - yes. I believe it's the easiest way of handling this situation and although perhaps not the most elegant it is certainly a functional solution/workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the empty scene to switch right back another scene to restart it.
At first it didn't work at all, I had to display a button in the empty scene, and attach a function to it, so that when the user presses it , it switches back to the old scene, which would restart it.

However, further Googling the problem, I found out that the Director class v. 1.3 and above, can reload the scene that you are in by simply calling it using the director:changeScene("") function!

(Read about it here:
http://rauberlabs.blogspot.com/2011/07/director-class-13.html )

So if you are in settings.lua, and you want to reload it, just include director:changeScene("settings") in the same settings.lua (as you did the first time).

of course remember to update the director.lua to the latest version.
I guess you can still download it from here:

https://bitbucket.org/ricardorauber/corona/downloads